# return type of getStyleableProperty

Tags: javafx

When you look docs about what returns a given CSSMetadata (getCSSmetadata) the function getStyleableProperty tells something about <? capture of extends styleable
what is the type and how does it work.
I try to cast -fx-max-width to ( easyno subproperties)  Styleable but does not work

```
    hbox.getCSSMetadata().stream().filter(prop -> prop.toString().constanis("-fx-max-width")).forEach(prop2->{
      prop2.getProperty(); //ok returns the string of the name
      prop2.getStyleableProperty(<????? what goes here and what is the type of the returned value>);
    });
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? This just looks like a complex way to get at `hbox.maxWidthProperty()`.

Comment: trying to obtain information and know more about making your own component (styleable via css of course)

Comment: _trying to obtain information and know more about making your own component_ that's not really an answer to @James_D comment, IMO ;) Anyway, either this question is unclear/two broad or smells of a wrong approach of whatever you try.

Answer (score 1):

Your `prop2` variable (which is not really well named) is of type `CSSMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>`.

The parameter you need to pass to the `getStyleableProperty(...)` method is the `Styleable` for which it's a property; since this `CSSMetaData` came from `hbox`, and I assume that's an `HBox`, then the parameter should be `hbox`.

However, the compiler will insist the parameter is the same type as the first type parameter to the `CSSMetaData`; since this is a wildcard type (`? extends Styleable`) there's no way for it to check this. So you need a downcast:

```
((CSSMetaData<HBox, ?>)prop2).getStyleableProperty(hbox)
```

The cast does not need to be this specific;

```
((CSSMetaData<Styleable, ?>)prop2).getStyleableProperty(hbox)
```

will also work (since `hbox` is an `HBox`, which is an implementation of `Styleable`).

Note that this is actually going to give you the `hbox`'s `maxWidthProperty()`, so really you could just do `hbox.maxWidthProperty()` instead. (But maybe your `-fx-max-width` is just a contrived example, and you are trying to get this dynamically for some reason.)

Note that it's almost always bad practice to check an object's `toString()` method to determine data about it. So you should replace

```
prop.toString().contains("-fx-max-width")
```

with

```
prop.getProperty().equals("-fx-max-width)
```

The return type of `getStyleableProperty()`, with this downcast, will be

```
StyleableProperty<?>
```

(since there is a wildcard for the second type parameter in the downcast). If you knew more information, as in this case, you can make that more specific if needed. For example, if you wanted to set the value, you would need to use the fact that the `-fx-max-width` CSS property is numeric, and use the downcast

```
StyleableProperty<Number> maxWidth = ((CSSMetaData<Styleable, Number>)prop2).getStyleableProperty(hbox);
```

and then the return type would be

```
StyleableProperty<Number>
```

and you'd be able to do, for example

```
maxWidth.setValue(400.0);
```

Here's an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.CssMetaData;
import javafx.css.Styleable;
import javafx.css.StyleableProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SPTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button show = new Button("Show");
        show.setOnAction(e -> {
            root.getCssMetaData().stream().filter(cssMD -> cssMD.getProperty().equals("-fx-max-width")).forEach(maxWidthMD -> {
                StyleableProperty<?> maxWidth = ((CssMetaData<Styleable, ?>)maxWidthMD).getStyleableProperty(root);
                System.out.println(maxWidth.getValue());
                System.out.println(maxWidth == root.maxWidthProperty());
            });
            System.out.println(root.getMaxWidth());
        });
        root.getChildren().add(show);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

I used a simple `style.css` file to test this:

```css
.root {
    -fx-max-width: 400 ;
}
```

Note the compiler has no way of checking the cast will work, so you get a compiler warning with this code. Since you're assured the cast will work (because the `CSSMetaData` was retrieved from the `hbox`), you can suppress this warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
StyleableProperty<?> maxWidth = ((CssMetaData<HBox, ?>)prop2).getStyleableProperty(root);
```